# Will Android Try to Restart an Application that has Crashed?

Tags: android, crash

Does Android attempt to restart installed applications that have crashed?  Is there some settings to request the OS to restart an application?

Comment: No but you can use sticky services to do something similar.

Comment: How could a sticky service which is part of the same? application help?  does a crashed app not also mean all services are down with it?

Comment: that is why i said similar,and not same. Crashed stickies are restarted by android.